# DBA_OBJECTS view in Oracle

Tags: oracle, view

The DBA_OBJECTS object is a view.  I was trying to look and see what the underlying tables of that view is.  Can those base tables be updated manually, and it be reflected in the view?

Can obj$ be updated manually?

Comment: *Why* would you want to alter Oracle's internally managed data dictionary in such a way - presumably - that it wouldn't accurately represent the state of the database?

Answer (score 2):

No. `obj$` cannot be updated manually. Only indirectly through execution of DDL statements that create, alter, or drop database objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the underlying objects by querying `dba_views`:

```
SELECT text
  FROM dba_views
 WHERE view_name = 'DBA_OBJECTS'
```

You will find that it is quite complex, undocumented and absolutely off limits for direct modification. Messing with dictionary objects can easily corrupt your dictionary and will earn you a dead-end in any SR you open with Oracle. But there's no harm in exploring the view definitions to understand the dictionary better, and in some cases, such as with advanced monitoring tools such as I write, there is benefit to querying base dictionary and fixed x$ objects directly, but never modifying anything.

The ***only*** exception to the above rule I have found is that there is a legitimate need for a DBA at times to modify the `ptime` column in `sys.user$` in order to spread out password expirations caused by creating too many users all at the same time (at database creation time, for example). But this is a rare situation and is only justified by the lack of any other means provided by Oracle to do this.